# Curious broadband puzzle

Tags: networking, ssl

I am using Virgin Media fibre broadband at home in the U.K.

We regularly get drop-outs and we have to reset the cable modem ( I am using the VM router in modem mode and plug in my own router - a Draytek ). When the drop-out happens all client machines in the home see the same problem - a web page will fail to load, a movie will stop streaming once it reaches the end of its buffer, connection to the email server etc will fail. The one exception to this is my VPN tunnel to my work PC which continues to work as a full Remote Desktop connection.

This means data must still be flowing, so to speak, but all normal connections fail. Ping fails. Direct connections to IP numbers fail ( sidestepping DNS ).

By the way, my DNS settings on my router are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Why does the VPN carry on working?

Comment: Sounds like it could be related to the bad Puma 6 chipset to me: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/01/netgear_puma_6_modems_trivial_to_crash/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as though the modem is running out of connections for NAT, and so is unable to open any new connections. Your VPN is working because it has an existing connection. Perhaps one of your devices is keeping a lot of connections open, by failing to close them properly.

Comment: The modem doesn't do NAT, the router does... apart from that, you may be right. idk the Draytek, but I use a similar setup with a Virgin Superhub in modem mode & Sophos UTM & haven't seen that issue ever. I also use Virgin's DNS, not Google's. I'd blame the Draytek.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated when/how your other clients' connections start working again (I'm reading your post to mean you need to restart the modem to regain your network connection after a drop out for your tunnel to keep working), but I assume you don't have to reboot every machine after your disconnect.

If your VPN is set to auto-reconnect, then there should be a brief interruption in connectivity. Your VPN software must have detected the connection loss and then re-established a connection. All the connections over the VPN itself keep running because, as far as applications see, there was a bit of packet loss rather than a complete disconnection. If your VPN runs over UDP instead of TCP, that may be another explanation for what you're seeing, but without more information, this seems less likely. I may also just be misunderstanding the situation you're describing.

For example, suppose your IP address from your ISP changes from 100.0.0.1 to 100.0.0.2 after the reconnect. Existing connections are obviously broken. But for applications tunnelled through your VPN, your VPN's tunnel interface maintains the same (VPN) IP address and just experienced some packet loss (even though the entire VPN had to reconnect to the other side).

Comment: The external WAN ip does not change. The Clint connections only begin working again once I reset the Virgin Media modem. But the VPN connection remains intact - in one case for several hours. Much to the annoyance of my family i refused to let anyone reboot the modem because I was trying to finish a piece of work through the VPN

Comment: Ah... I read "drop out" to mean a signal syncing error for the modem that caused a disconnection that was rectified by resetting it. Is your router acting as a switch or as a router? Are your clients able to reach the modem? How about the router (if running in router mode)? And are you able to send UDP packets to the Internet during the drop-out-pre-reset period?

Comment: Virgin Media super hub in "modem mode" and behind that a Draytek router acting as a router (but no WiFi - I have separate APs) and doing DHCP. Yes clients can reach all points on the LAN including the LAN side of the Virgin Media modem and the Draytek router. Don't know about the UDP packets - I don't think so but haven't directly tested this. I will check next time I get a connection failure

Comment: Another test you might try to run is to see if you can reach your modem from the Internet (assuming it responds to pings to begin with) and to see what happens if you reboot your router. I don't have any specific hypotheses that these are testing; just figured it might be useful to know for diagnostics.